using nix to build an interdependent library of both Rust and Python code modules
goal
I'm trying to write a nix derivation to build calyx (and to also run all tests to check the build/install). The calyx library is comprised of a few different code modules, including both Rust and Python code. The code modules are all interdependent and thus the test for checking each module's build requires all modules to be built first. (The Python module also requires the source code itself to run correctly? not sure why.)
See full build instructions here, specifically the sections "Installing from Source" (this is the Rust module), "Installing the Command-Line Driver" (this is the Python module) and "Running Core Tests".
approach
My approach was to write the derivation like so:

build the Rust subfolder calyx with rustPlatform.buildRustPackage, turn off test checks
build the Python subfolder calyx-py with pkgs.buildPythonPackage, turn off test checks
build the Python subfolder fud with pkgs.buildPythonPackage, turn off test checks
link src (which we need for fud) & the above packages together with symlinkJoin

here run the config steps for fud in the fixup phase
here use runt (built separately in its own expression with rustPlatform.buildRustPackage) to run the checks for calyx & fud in the installCheck phase



the full calyx nix expression is below:
{
  # source code repo
  src,
  # nix stdlib
  lib,
  rustPlatform,
  # dependencies
  python3,
  python3Packages,
  runt,
  calyx,
  jq,
  z3,
  cvc5,
  whichSmt ? "z3",
}:

let
  srcTomlMeta = (builtins.fromTOML (builtins.readFile "${src}/Cargo.toml")).workspace.package;
  smt =
    if (whichSmt == "z3") then
      z3
    else if (whichSmt == "cvc5") then
      cvc5
    else
      throw "invalid value for `whichSmt`; must be either \"z3\" or \"cvc5\"";
in
rustPlatform.buildRustPackage {
  pname = "filament";
  version = srcTomlMeta.version;

  inherit src;
  cargoPatches = [ ./add-Cargo.lock.patch ];
  cargoHash = "sha256-VMsjEP4/ivVe2UrXuZvMuiEhIr8RruHOX/e2kL0CJgU=";

  nativeBuildInputs = [
    python3
    python3Packages.numpy
    runt
    calyx
    jq
    smt
  ];

  patches = [ ./runt.toml.patch ];
  doCheck = false;
  doInstallCheck = true;
  installCheckPhase = ''
    ln -s $out ./result
    runt -d
    rm ./result
  '';

  meta = {
    inherit (srcTomlMeta) description homepage;
    license = lib.licenses.mit;
    platforms = lib.platforms.all;
  };
}

this I can build successfully via the below shell command:
nix-build -E 'let pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {}; in pkgs.callPackage ./calyx/package.nix {runt = pkgs.callPackage ./runt/package.nix {}; }'

problem
I then try to make a shell with calyx loaded via the command-line expression
nix-shell -E 'let pkgs = (import <nixpkgs> {}); in pkgs.mkShell { buildInputs = [pkgs.callPackage ./calyx/package.nix {runt = pkgs.callPackage ./runt/package.nix {}; } ]; }' --show-trace

which generates the error error: Dependency is not of a valid type: element 1 of buildInputs for nix-shell. the full error trace is pasted below:
error:
       … while calling the 'derivationStrict' builtin
         at <nix/derivation-internal.nix>:9:12:
            8|
            9|   strict = derivationStrict drvAttrs;
             |            ^
           10|

       … while evaluating derivation 'nix-shell'
         whose name attribute is located at /nix/store/lbmzs66dzl6vp7klrplq0c607s7majp9-source/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:336:7

       … while evaluating attribute '__impureHostDeps' of derivation 'nix-shell'
         at /nix/store/lbmzs66dzl6vp7klrplq0c607s7majp9-source/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:451:7:
          450|       __propagatedSandboxProfile = unique (computedPropagatedSandboxProfile ++ [ propagatedSandboxProfile ]);
          451|       __impureHostDeps = computedImpureHostDeps ++ computedPropagatedImpureHostDeps ++ __propagatedImpureHostDeps ++ __impureHostDeps ++ stdenv.__extraImpureHostDeps ++ [
             |       ^
          452|         "/dev/zero"

       … while calling the 'foldl'' builtin
         at /nix/store/lbmzs66dzl6vp7klrplq0c607s7majp9-source/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:435:11:
          434|         computedImpureHostDeps =
          435|           unique (concatMap (input: input.__propagatedImpureHostDeps or [])
             |           ^
          436|             (stdenv.extraNativeBuildInputs

       … while calling the 'concatMap' builtin
         at /nix/store/lbmzs66dzl6vp7klrplq0c607s7majp9-source/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:435:19:
          434|         computedImpureHostDeps =
          435|           unique (concatMap (input: input.__propagatedImpureHostDeps or [])
             |                   ^
          436|             (stdenv.extraNativeBuildInputs

       … while calling anonymous lambda
         at /nix/store/lbmzs66dzl6vp7klrplq0c607s7majp9-source/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:435:30:
          434|         computedImpureHostDeps =
          435|           unique (concatMap (input: input.__propagatedImpureHostDeps or [])
             |                              ^
          436|             (stdenv.extraNativeBuildInputs

       … from call site
         at /nix/store/lbmzs66dzl6vp7klrplq0c607s7majp9-source/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:435:37:
          434|         computedImpureHostDeps =
          435|           unique (concatMap (input: input.__propagatedImpureHostDeps or [])
             |                                     ^
          436|             (stdenv.extraNativeBuildInputs

       … while calling anonymous lambda
         at /nix/store/lbmzs66dzl6vp7klrplq0c607s7majp9-source/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:312:13:
          311|       (map (drv: getDev drv.__spliced.hostHost or drv) (checkDependencyList "depsHostHost" depsHostHost))
          312|       (map (drv: getDev drv.__spliced.hostTarget or drv) (checkDependencyList "buildInputs" buildInputs'))
             |             ^
          313|     ]

       … from call site
         at /nix/store/lbmzs66dzl6vp7klrplq0c607s7majp9-source/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:312:18:
          311|       (map (drv: getDev drv.__spliced.hostHost or drv) (checkDependencyList "depsHostHost" depsHostHost))
          312|       (map (drv: getDev drv.__spliced.hostTarget or drv) (checkDependencyList "buildInputs" buildInputs'))
             |                  ^
          313|     ]

       … while calling 'getOutput'
         at /nix/store/lbmzs66dzl6vp7klrplq0c607s7majp9-source/lib/attrsets.nix:1797:23:
         1796|   */
         1797|   getOutput = output: pkg:
             |                       ^
         1798|     if ! pkg ? outputSpecified || ! pkg.outputSpecified

       … while evaluating a branch condition
         at /nix/store/lbmzs66dzl6vp7klrplq0c607s7majp9-source/lib/attrsets.nix:1798:5:
         1797|   getOutput = output: pkg:
         1798|     if ! pkg ? outputSpecified || ! pkg.outputSpecified
             |     ^
         1799|       then pkg.${output} or pkg.out or pkg

       … in the left operand of the OR (||) operator
         at /nix/store/lbmzs66dzl6vp7klrplq0c607s7majp9-source/lib/attrsets.nix:1798:32:
         1797|   getOutput = output: pkg:
         1798|     if ! pkg ? outputSpecified || ! pkg.outputSpecified
             |                                ^
         1799|       then pkg.${output} or pkg.out or pkg

       … in the argument of the not operator
         at /nix/store/lbmzs66dzl6vp7klrplq0c607s7majp9-source/lib/attrsets.nix:1798:10:
         1797|   getOutput = output: pkg:
         1798|     if ! pkg ? outputSpecified || ! pkg.outputSpecified
             |          ^
         1799|       then pkg.${output} or pkg.out or pkg

       … from call site
         at /nix/store/lbmzs66dzl6vp7klrplq0c607s7majp9-source/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:312:25:
          311|       (map (drv: getDev drv.__spliced.hostHost or drv) (checkDependencyList "depsHostHost" depsHostHost))
          312|       (map (drv: getDev drv.__spliced.hostTarget or drv) (checkDependencyList "buildInputs" buildInputs'))
             |                         ^
          313|     ]

       … while calling anonymous lambda
         at /nix/store/lbmzs66dzl6vp7klrplq0c607s7majp9-source/lib/lists.nix:334:29:
          333|   */
          334|   imap1 = f: list: genList (n: f (n + 1) (elemAt list n)) (length list);
             |                             ^
          335|

       … from call site
         at /nix/store/lbmzs66dzl6vp7klrplq0c607s7majp9-source/lib/lists.nix:334:32:
          333|   */
          334|   imap1 = f: list: genList (n: f (n + 1) (elemAt list n)) (length list);
             |                                ^
          335|

       … while calling anonymous lambda
         at /nix/store/lbmzs66dzl6vp7klrplq0c607s7majp9-source/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:281:15:
          280|     imap1
          281|       (index: dep:
             |               ^
          282|         if isDerivation dep || dep == null || builtins.isString dep || builtins.isPath dep then dep

       … while calling the 'throw' builtin
         at /nix/store/lbmzs66dzl6vp7klrplq0c607s7majp9-source/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:284:14:
          283|         else if isList dep then checkDependencyList' ([index] ++ positions) name dep
          284|         else throw "Dependency is not of a valid type: ${concatMapStrings (ix: "element ${toString ix} of ") ([index] ++ positions)}${name} for ${attrs.name or attrs.pname}")
             |              ^
          285|       deps;

       error: Dependency is not of a valid type: element 1 of buildInputs for nix-shell

question

what does this error mean?
what am I doing wrong here? how can I build this package in nix?

